# hide/display img tag on condition

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, html, css

I have below code -

```
Var @test

<a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com/videos" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/sites/default/files/images/2015/12/121615-social-video.png" alt="videos" width="37" height="37"style="border:none;"/></a>
```

`@test` --> is a variable

I want when `@test`="India"` then the above image should get hide.

Regards

Comment: What's the context?  An email?  A microsite page?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at the [AMPScript Syntax Guide](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/).  It spells out how the conditionals are structured.

```
%%[

var @test
set @test = AttributeValue("TESTPERSONALIZATIONSTRING")

if @test == "India" then
]%%
<a href="http://example.com/videos"><img src="http://example.com/videos.png"/></a>
%%[ else ]%%
<!-- Not India -->
%%[ endif ]%%
```